# pythonでget引数にjavascriptでencodeURIComponent()したurlを渡したらcgi.FieldStrage()がおかしくなる

Tags: python

jsからlocalhostで動いているpythonにリクエストを送ってます。

jsではget引数にmain.py?url={jsでencodeURIComponentしたURL}という形でリクエストしています。

受け取り側では

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
form['url'].value
```

という形で取得しています。

jsでencodeURIComponentする前のURLが「http://example.com/」のような場合には問題なく取得できるのですが「http://example.com/?hoge=fuga」のようにこちらにもget引数がついていると、その部分がcgi.FieldStorage()で取得されてしまい、逆に'url'というキーの値がない、という状態になっています。

こういう場合、pythonではどのように受け取るべきなのでしょうか。

ちなみに、リクエストしているURLを直接ブラウザで叩いても同じ状態になります。

Comment: 実際のコードを見せるとより細かな回答が得られやすくなります。

Comment: そうですね、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

動作確認にPythonの標準ライブラリのサーバを使っている事と思いますが、そのサーバの問題です。手元でも`python3 -m http.server --cgi`で起動したサーバで再現しました。CGIはそのままで、他のサーバでは動くはずです。

`cgi.FieldStorage()`はサーバが用意した環境変数`QUERY_STRING`を使用すると思うのですが、標準ライブラリのサーバはこれが大雑把で、urlを`rfind('?')`で分割して使っているようです。

`http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/cgi-try.py?url=http://example.com/?hoge=fuga` という url だと、通常のサーバから渡される`QUERY_STRING`は`url=http://example.com/?hoge=fuga`だと思いますが Python のサーバでは`hoge=fuga`になってしまいます。

(こういう物なのか、バグと考えるべきなのか分かりません)

Comment: > CGIはそのままで、他のサーバでは動くはずです。

この点安心しました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

僕がテストする限りとくに問題なく動きました。ブラウザのJavaScriptコンソールで`encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/?hoge=fuga')`とすると`http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fhoge%3Dfuga`が得られます。

テストプログラム test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print 'Content-Type: text/html'
print
print form['url'].value
```

端末で

```
mkdir cgi-bin
# 上のtest.pyをcgi-binの下に保存して実行属性をつける
chmod 755 cgi-bin/test.py

# CGIサーバ起動
python -m CGIHTTPServer
```

ブラウザで`http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/test.py?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fhoge%3Dfuga`をアクセス

ソースを確認すると`http://example.com/?hoge=fuga`が正しく得られました。